# Replacing letters in specific position in string w/regex(javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/cQ4uNQ/1) (regex101).

```
\b([\w])(\w*?)\1
```

Substitution: `$1$2#`

What I need to do is in JavaScript I iterate thru the chosen and guessed words and am currently checking each position for matches. I have a variable i that holds the current position that I would like to substitute the character `#` for if both letters in the current position match.

Example, If the current words are `mummy` and the guessed word is `mommy` after first iteration we would `#ummy` & `#ommy`. After checking 3rd position would have `#u#my` & `#o#my`. and etc till end would have `#u##y` & `#o##y`.

And can I substitute variables into my regex to accommodate different word pairs. So on another iteration if words were `apple` and `maple` code would transform two strings to `ap#ple` & `ma#ple`. My JavaScript looks like :

```
      const regex = /\b([\w])(\w*?)\1/gm;
      const subst = `$1$2#`;
      wirdleString = wirdleString.replace(regex, subst);
      guessString = guessString.replace(regex, subst);
```

I'm sorry my regex skills are very weak. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

First of all: I don't think this is a task for regexps. The problem is much easier solved using iteration.

That said, as an academic exercise, here's one go to match all characters that differ from "mummy":

```
(?<=.{0})m(?=.{4})|
(?<=.{1})u(?=.{3})|
(?<=.{2})m(?=.{2})|
(?<=.{3})m(?=.{1})|
(?<=.{3})y(?=.{0})
```

You can create this by a mapping like this:

```
const string = "mummy";
const length = string.length;
const exp = string.split('').map((char, index) => 
    `(?<=.{${index}})${char}(?=.{${length - index -1}})`
  ).join('|');

const attempt = "momma";
const result = attempt.replace(new RegExp(exp, 'g'), "#");

// '#o##a'
```

On a general note, I think an iterative approach would be easier and definitely faster:

```
const result = [...string].map((char, index) => 
    attempt[index] == char ? '#' : char
  ).join('');
```